# Anyway to access a join table in Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models - `Question`, `Tag`.

I would like to do a `count` on the number of records in my `questions_tags` join table.

How can I do that from the Rails Console?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have no join model (just a join table), you can execute some arbitrary SQL through one of your existing models to get a count:

```
Question.connection.execute "select count(*) from questions_tags"
```

This will get you a db-dependent result object.  For PostgreSQL, to get an actual integer out of it with:

```
Question.connection.execute("select count(*) from questions_tags").first["count"].to_i
```

Comment: I don't know of a more "Railsy" way to do this, but since your question was about accessing from the console, I figured you're just looking for a quick way to count them for debugging or whatever.  I wouldn't recommend the above code in production.  If you needed a count of the join table in your app, you might want to look into elevating it to a real join model.

Comment: Yeh...you are right....this is for debugging purposes. When you run these sorts of queries on a join table that has a lot of records (say 20K) does it usually take very long? I ran it, almost 2 mins after you posted it and it is still running.

Comment: That depends a lot on the underlying database, but I'm surprised that a `count(*)` would take any real time at all.  Most DBs know the cardinality of all their tables without having to compute it.  If your query is more complext than the simple example above, then it could be due to a lack of indices on the table.  DB performance is a very complex issue in general.

Comment: Ok.....my bad...this is the result: `>Question.connection.execute("select count(*) from questions_tags").first["count"].to_i
   (648978.7ms)  select count(*) from questions_tags
 => 39919778`. So a bit more than the 20K I assumed.

Comment: So I ran just the `select count * from questions_tags` at the `psql` command line and it outputted this:  `count  ---------- 39919778 (1 row)` What's up with the `1 row`? Does it mean all of those records are in 1 row? Or just the results returned are 1 row?

Comment: The result set contains one row, with one field (`count`) with the value `39919778`.  SQL generally presents all output in table format, even if it's just a temporary pseudo-table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26067/discussion-between-jim-stewart-and-marcamillion)